# Can't understand the document of @Async annotation in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm reading the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) of @Async annotation and the following sentences confuse me.

> A Future handle returned from the proxy will be an actual asynchronous Future that can be used to track the result of the asynchronous method execution. However, since the target method needs to implement the same signature, it will have to return a temporary Future handle that just passes a value through: e.g. Spring's AsyncResult, EJB 3.1's AsyncResult, or CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Object).

I wonder what `a Future handle returned from the proxy` is. I know Future in Java but what is a Future handle? What does the proxy refer to? What is `a temporary Future handle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is a Future handle?

You can read it as "A Future instance" or "A Future object".

> What does the proxy refer to?

When you call an async method of bean B from bean A, Spring automatically submits a task to an executor so that the method is executed in a separate thread, asynchronously. That is possible because the bean B that it injects in A is not an actual instance of the B class you created. It's in fact an instance of a dynamic proxy, which delegates to the instance of the actual instance of the B class. It's this proxy which handles the task submission to the executor, the creation of the Future, etc. Just as when you call a transactional method, it's also a proxy that automatically starts the transaction before calling the actual method.

> What is a temporary Future handle?

It's the instance of `Future` that you create in your actual method, and which is not the actual `Future` returned to the caller, but which simply wraps the result of the method.